# Get URL code not the whole URL

Tags: php, string, url, echo

my php function is

```
$exp3 = $_GET["url"]; 
echo $exp3;
```

This function gets me this link for example

```
"http://www.streamuj.tv/video/687aa15fe046f21cc1e3"
```

What do I need is to transform this function to get just the code of the url. In this case its `687aa15fe046f21cc1e3`.

Can you please help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explode and get the last

```
  $myArray= explode('/',$exp3 );
  $my_Last = end($myArray);

 echo $my_last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$code = array_pop(explode('/', $exp3));
echo $code;
```